# CutyCapt freezing

Tags: command-line-interface, freeze, cutycapt

For my new application I want to serve screenshots of websites. I have a list with over 1 million domain names.

Right now I created a little php script and run this in a screen from command line. It works well but the script is hanging sometimes because the process is frozen (can't make the screenshot because of some reason?)

What kind of solution could I try to not stop my script till I restart it by myself?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on Windows.  Here is my solution.

I use [killProcess for windows](http://www.softtreetech.com/24x7/archive/49.htm)

```
$cmd="$path/CutyCapt.exe --js-can-open-windows=off --max-wait=60000 --url=\"http://$url\" --out=\"$fname\"";

$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
   2 => array("pipe", "w", "a") // stderr is a file to write to
);

$process = proc_open($cmd,$descriptorspec,$pipes);
if(!is_resource($process)) {
    throw new Exception('Exec could not be started.');
}

//we wwait upto 1 min
$sec=0;
while(1)
{
    sleep(1);
    $status = proc_get_status($process);
    if(!$status["running"]) 
        break;
    echo $sec++.' ';flush();
    if($sec>60)
        break;
}
if($status["running"])
{
    system("KillProcess.exe CutyCapt.exe");    
}
proc_close($process);

if($status["running"])
{
    echo ("CutyCapt can't save image!");
    @unlink($fname);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need run another thread to make sure it will kill cutycapt itself. Timer does not work in this case because it is caused by the event loop of QT is full.

```
    class ThreadTimer : public QThread
    {
         Q_OBJECT
     public:
     protected:
     private:
         void run();
    };
    void ThreadTimer::run()
    {
            QThread::currentThread()->setPriority(QThread::HighPriority);
            int timeout = 180;//how many seconds you want to time out
            while(timeout > 0){
                sleep(10);
                timeout = timeout - 10;
            }

            qCritical() << "WARNING:Force quit by timer!";

            qint64 pid = QCoreApplication::applicationPid();
            QProcess::startDetached("kill -9 " + QString::number(pid));
    }
```

I also recommend this. We have tested 1.5 million websites and everything is fine. You need get one API key by yourself.

```
    <?php
    $apikey = "854412b0648e9338";
    $api_url = "http://api.page2images.com/restfullink";

    function call_p2i()
    {
        global $apikey, $api_url;
        // URL can be those formats: http://www.google.com https://google.com google.com and www.google.com
        $url = "http://www.google.com";
        $device = 0; // 0 - iPhone4, 1 - iPhone5, 2 - Android, 3 - WinPhone, 4 - iPad, 5 - Android Pad, 6 - Desktop
        $loop_flag = TRUE;
        $timeout = 120; // timeout after 120 seconds
        set_time_limit($timeout+10);
        $start_time = time();
        $timeout_flag = false;

        while ($loop_flag) {
            // We need call the API until we get the screenshot or error message
            try {
                $para = array(
                    "p2i_url" => $url,
                    "p2i_key" => $apikey,
                    "p2i_device" => $device
                );
                // connect page2images server
                $response = connect($api_url, $para);

                if (empty($response)) {
                    $loop_flag = FALSE;
                    // something error
                    echo "something error";
                    break;
                } else {
                    $json_data = json_decode($response);
                    if (empty($json_data->status)) {
                        $loop_flag = FALSE;
                        // api error
                        break;
                    }
                }
                switch ($json_data->status) {
                    case "error":
                        // do something to handle error
                        $loop_flag = FALSE;
                        echo $json_data->errno . " " . $json_data->msg;
                        break;
                    case "finished":
                        // do something with finished. For example, show this image
                        echo "<img src='$json_data->image_url'>";
                        // Or you can download the image from our server
                        $loop_flag = FALSE;
                        break;
                    case "processing":
                    default:
                        if ((time() - $start_time) > $timeout) {
                            $loop_flag = false;
                            $timeout_flag = true; // set the timeout flag. You can handle it later.
                        } else {
                            sleep(3); // This only work on windows.
                        }
                        break;
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // Do whatever you think is right to handle the exception.
                $loop_flag = FALSE;
                echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
            }
        }

        if ($timeout_flag) {
            // handle the timeout event here
            echo "Error: Timeout after $timeout seconds.";
        }
    }
    // curl to connect server
    function connect($url, $para)
    {
        if (empty($para)) {
            return false;
        }
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($para));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    }

    function call_p2i_with_callback()
    {
        global $apikey, $api_url;
        // URL can be those formats: http://www.google.com https://google.com google.com and www.google.com
        $url = "http://www.google.com";
        // 0 - iPhone4, 1 - iPhone5, 2 - Android, 3 - WinPhone, 4 - iPad, 5 - Android Pad, 6 - Desktop
        $device = 0;

        // you can pass us any parameters you like. We will pass it back.
        // Please make sure http://your_server_domain/api_callback can handle our call
        $callback_url = "http://your_server_domain/api_callback?image_id=your_unique_image_id_here";
        $para = array(
                    "p2i_url" => $url,
                    "p2i_key" => $apikey,
                    "p2i_device" => $device
                );
        $response = connect($api_url, $para);

        if (empty($response)) {
            // Do whatever you think is right to handle the exception.
        } else {
            $json_data = json_decode($response);
            if (empty($json_data->status)) {
                // api error do something
                echo "api error";
            }else
            {
                //do anything
                echo $json_data->status;
            }
        }

    }

    // This function demo how to handle the callback request
    function api_callback()
    {
        if (! empty($_REQUEST["image_id"])) {
            // do anything you want about the unique image id. We suggest to use it to identify which url you send to us since you can send 1,000 at one time.
        }

        if (! empty($_POST["result"])) {
            $post_data = $_POST["result"];
            $json_data = json_decode($post_data);
            switch ($json_data->status) {
                case "error":
                    // do something with error
                    echo $json_data->errno . " " . $json_data->msg;
                    break;
                case "finished":
                    // do something with finished
                    echo $json_data->image_url;
                    // Or you can download the image from our server
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            // Do whatever you think is right to handle the exception.
            echo "Error: Empty";
        }
    }
```